# How to keep track of dependencies in Python?

Tags: python, version-control, dependency-management

I am new to Python programming. Recently, I wrote a code which worked well. However, I needed to reinstall my Anaconda distribution and install the libraries I needed again. Then the code started to break. The version of Python I installed wouldn't support f-strings, although I did not use `openpyxl` directly, but it seems Pandas needed it, and some other behaviors which I think was due to using a different version of PyQt5.
How can I have a database of packages that my program uses with dependencies of said packages with their version number? Should I manually keep track of them, or is there some software or service to help?

Answer (score 5):

I would generate a new virtual environment for your project

```
python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/env
```

Then I would use pip to manage my packages

```
pip install <package>
```

And then I would just generate a `requirements.txt` file every time I change my dependencies with

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

At this point, if you have to move your project on another machine or in another environment, I would just re-install all dependencies from the `requirements.txt` file with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```